# python email.parser: extract header from email

Tags: python

```
import sys, imaplib
    from email.parser import HeaderParser

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER, PORT)
status, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

for msg_id in data[0].split():
  status, message = mail.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
  print message[0][1]

mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

I am trying to fetch emails from gmail via imap. All works fine, except that I am not able to extract header (subject, sender, date) from the message. In the above code, message[0][1] contains my email.

The only way I am able to get the header is to ask the imap server again, specifically for header:

```
status, message = mail.fetch(msg_id, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')
parser = HeaderParser()
header = parser.parsestr(message[0][1])
print header
```

could somebody please advise how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you've got the full email, not only the message body.

```
raw_message = """From: Santa Claus <santa@aintreal.no>
To: Some Dude <some@du.de>
Subject: I have lost your presents.

Dude, i am so sorry.
"""

import email
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_message)
print(msg['Subject'])  # "I have lost your presents."
```

`msg` is a [`email.message.Message`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) object.